# Azure backup report generation and notification

Tags: azure

Is there any other way than Using PowerBi for reports and getting an email notification from Backup alerts pan in recovery vault credentials.
How to setup alerts and event notification through Microsoft Flow??

Comment: have you checked [this article](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-set-data-alerts/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Power BI is the only option to [configure Azure Backup reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-configure-reports). From the Azure Portal you can now monitor cloud backups for your on-premises servers and Azure IaaS virtual machines in a single dashboard. In addition, you can also configure [email notifications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/alerting-and-monitoring-for-azure-backup/) for all backup alerts.